# Why the moment-generating function does not always exist

Tags: stochastic-processes, characteristic-functions, moment-generating-functions

Why the moment-generating function $M(t)=E\left(e^{tx}
\right)$
does not always exist while the characteristic function $\varphi(\epsilon)=E\left(e^{i\epsilon x}\right)$
exists for any random variable X?

Comment: $e^{itx}$ is bounded but $e^{tx}$ is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter example is Cauchy distribution.

moment generating funciton does not exist , but characteristic function exists.

Since $E(e^{tx})$ is not absolutely convergent

Comment: Thank you for answer me. But how about the maximum entropy distribution?